# How to place a component's logic outside the file .vue itself

Tags: vue.js, methods, components, nuxt.js

I'm building a webapp in Nuxt.js and it's growing quite a bit.
I have a page which does two things: one when i'm creating a task and one when managing that task.
This page has a lot of methods, divided for when i create the task and when i manage the task.
How can i split these modules in two files and then import then only when I need them?

These methods need also to access the component's state and other function Nuxt imports such as axios.

```js
async create() {
      if (this.isSondaggioReady()) {
        try {
          await this.getImagesPath()
          const o = { ...this.sondaggio }
          delete o.id
          o.questions = o.questions.map((question) => {
            delete question.garbageCollector
            if (question.type !== 'checkbox' && question.type !== 'radio') {
              delete question.answers
              delete question.hasAltro
            } else {
              question.answers = question.answers.map((answer) => {
                delete answer._id
                delete answer.file
                delete answer.error
                if (answer.type !== 'image') delete answer.caption
                return answer
              })
            }
            if (question.hasAltro) {
              question.answers.push({
                type: 'altro',
                value: ''
              })
            }
            return question
          })
          console.log('TO SEND', JSON.stringify(o, null, 2))
          this.$store.commit('temp/showBottomLoader', {
            show: true,
            message: 'Crezione del sondaggio in corso'
          })
          const { data } = await this.$axios.post('/sondaggi/admin/create', o)
          this.sondaggio.id = data
          const s = {
            _id: data,
            author: this.$auth.user.email.slice(0, -13),
            title: this.sondaggio.title
          }
          this.$store.commit('temp/pushHome', { key: 'sondaggi', attr: 'data', data: [...this.$store.state.temp.home.sondaggi.data, s] })
          this.$store.dispatch('temp/showToast', 'Sondaggio creato correttamente')
          this.$router.replace('/')
        } catch (e) {
          console.log(e)
          this.$store.dispatch('temp/showToast', this.$getErrorMessage(e))
        } finally {
          this.$store.commit('temp/showBottomLoader', {
            show: false,
            message: 'Crezione del sondaggio in corso'
          })
        }
      }
    },
```

Here there's an example of what a method does. It calls an async functions which relies on HTTP axios requests:

```js
    async getImagesPath() {
      this.sondaggio.questions.forEach((question, i) => {
        question.answers.forEach((answer, j) => {
          if (answer.file instanceof File || answer.value.includes('data:image')) {
            this.uploadingImages.push({
              coords: [i, j],
              percentage: 0,
              file: answer.file || answer.value
            })
          }
        })
      })
      const requests = []
      this.uploadingImages.forEach((img) => {
        const temp = new FormData()
        temp.append('img', img.file)
        const req = this.$axios.post('/sondaggi/admin/images/add/' + this.sondaggio.title.replace(/\s+/g, ''), temp, {
          onUploadProgress: function (progressEvent) {
            img.percentage = Math.round(((progressEvent.loaded * 100) / progressEvent.total) * 90 / 100)
          },
          onDownloadProgress: function (progressEvent) {
            img.percentage = 90 + Math.round(((progressEvent.loaded * 100) / progressEvent.total) * 10 / 100)
          },
          headers: { 'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data' }
        })
          .catch((err) => {
            console.log(err)
            img.percentage = 150
          })
        requests.push(req)
      })
      try {
        const response = await Promise.all(requests)
        response.forEach(({ data }, i) => {
          this.sondaggio.questions[this.uploadingImages[i].coords[0]].answers[this.uploadingImages[i].coords[1]].value = data[0]
        })
        this.$set(this.sondaggio, 'hasImages', this.uploadingImages.length > 0)
        this.uploadingImages = []
        await Promise.resolve()
      } catch (e) {
        console.log('handling gloval err', e)
        await Promise.reject(e)
      }
    },
```

As you can see axios requests modify the component's state

Comment: You can use [Mixins](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/mixins.html) to distribute reusable functionalities for Vue components.

Comment: @palaѕн are then mixins importable only when needed? because the code is only needed in one page so I would't like to have that code like globally imported. If so, could you past some code please?

Comment: you can move away the logic of managing the task in a separate file, say, 'src/manager/taskManager.js` and export relevant functions from there, which you can then use in your main component by importing. This should DRY your code and abstract the business logic

Comment: @kiddorails how can i access to the component's state then? And how can import them (since they're two file for sure) dynamically only when needed?

Comment: the logic you move in other file shouldn't change the component state but run some logic and give the results which your main component can use. It's difficult to tell more without seeing the code

Comment: @kiddorails I added some code, I hope you can help

Comment: Note that in Vue 3, composition API is favored to mixins: https://vuejs.org/api/options-composition.html#mixins